# Soundcloud JS SDK is not working with IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, soundcloud

When querying tracks via the soundcloud javascript SDK, no requests are sent in IE9 e.g.

```
// initialize soundcloud app
SC.initialize({
  client_id: MY_USER_ID
});
SC.get("/groups/55517/tracks", {limit: 1}, function(tracks){
    console.log("Latest track: " + tracks[0].title);
});
```

It works in all other browsers and IE10 though. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Hey, I just tried your code in IE9 and it seems to work for me – http://jsbin.com/#/oqamov/1/edit

Comment: It works for me if I test it in IE10 with mode switched to IE9, but it does not work for me in a true IE9. In which one did you try it?

Comment: real IE9 on Win7. are you sure that IE9 is not on compatibility mode somehow?

Comment: Ok, so the problem was that I needed to update Adobe Flash to 10.1 or higher. So soundcloud seems to use a Flash based fallback in IE9. At Jsbin he showed me an overlay with a hint that this is required (which led me to the solution). However this hint was not displayed in our webapp for reasons unknown...

Comment: Unfortunately, we still have to rely on Flash for playback for various reasons, such as inability to efficiently deliver content to the client with HTML5 Audio

Comment: If you can, please put the solution in the answer and mark it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update Adobe Flash to 10.1 or higher. Soundcloud uses a Flash based fallback in IE9. Normally a hint is displayed but since I used it in a modal, the modal was lying over the hint!